# Is there a polyhedron all of whose faces are distinct polyominoes?

Tags: polyhedra, polyomino

The title is pretty much the complete question. An example of this would (I believe) have to be a nonconvex polycube. If there is one, I am also interested in the smallest example.

The analogous question for other planar polyforms, such as [polyabolos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyabolo), is also of interest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The smallest example I have found so far contains $16$ cubes:

[image]

It has six rectangular faces of dimensions $1\times 1, 1\times2, 1\times3, 1\times4, 2\times3,$ and $3\times3,$ as well as four nonconvex faces.

After writing some code, I've confirmed that every polycube with at most $10$ cells lacks this property, so $11$ is a lower bound.

Comment: Nice! Exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. My clumsy attempts kept getting stuck with more than one "finger" ending in a monomino. Thanks.